# Problema con procedimiento almacenado en SQL Developer - SP no está "actualizado" - incluso después de compilar

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

La siguiente pregunta también la formulé en [Stack Overflow (*en inglés*)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64507949/12511801), pero no he obtenido más respuestas desde entones - luego de haber intentado lo sugerido en aquella entrada y llevar mas de una semana con este problema.

> El problema que estoy enfrentando no es con la lógica del negocio, si no con el procedimiento almacenado (SP) en sí. Es un problema muy raro el que estoy teniendo y no había tenido un problema similar.

---

Estoy modificando un procedimiento almacenado - (*abreviado `SP`*) - llamado "`MY_STORED_PROC`" - y, cada vez que cambio su contenido, compilo, guardo los cambios, pero, los cambios anteriores siguen en el resultado de la ejecución del SP.

Este es el ejemplo del procedimiento almacenado:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MY_STORED_PROC
(
    V_USER IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    V_NUMBER_PARAM IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
    V_ORIGIN IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0
)
AS
    CV_1                    SYS_REFCURSOR; 
    V_SAMPLE                NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT  BAP.APA_CNAME
    INTO    V_USER_DB
    FROM    BH_APPLICATION_PARAM BAP
    WHERE   BAP.APA_NCODE = 84;
        
    INSERT INTO T_DEBUG (ERR_LINE, MESSAGE_INFO)
    SELECT ID, 'EXAMPLE_MESSAGE'
    FROM BH_VAL_MESSAGES; 
    
END MY_STORED_PROC;
```

En la estructura anterior, yo tengo un string `EXAMPLE_MESSAGE` el cual es insertado en la tabla llamada `T_DEBUG` cuando este SP es ejecutado y la condición se cumple.

Ahora, después de cambiar el string `EXAMPLE_MESSAGE` con otro texto y compilar y ejecutar el SP, el string `EXAMPLE_MESSAGE` se sigue mostrando en los resultados.

> Yo no entiendo por qué - si solo este SP tiene el string de ejemplo dado
> y la tabla `T_DEBUG` es truncada (`datos eliminados`) antes de que se ejecute el SP.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

- Borrar los datos de la tabla así: `DELETE FROM T_DEBUG;` y `TRUNCATE TABLE T_DEBUG` *ANTES* de llamar al SP.
- Ejecutar `DROP PROCEDURE MY_STORED_PROC`, luego, ejecuto `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_STORED_PROC` (*con y sin declarar el nombre de esquema*) con la lógica del SP completamente cambiada.
- Selecionar las opciones "Compilar" y "Compilar para depuración" para compilar el SP - es decir,  `MY_STORED_PROC` con y sin el nombre del esquema.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <SCHEMA>.MY_STORED_PROC ...
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_STORED_PROC ...
```

- Modificar el SP para truncar la tabla `T_DEBUG` "la cual contiene el string de ejemplo" - esta acción  (*antes de que el SP ejecute cualquier acción "`es decir, inserte datos en la tabla T_DEBUG`"*).
- Borrar el procedimiento almacenado así: `DROP PROCEDURE MY_STORED_PROC;` y ejecutar: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <SCHEMA>.MY_STORED_PROC ...`.
- Revisar la tabla `T_DEBUG` y no contiene ningún trigger u algo que le agregue registros desde otra parte del programa - la tabla `T_DEBUG` es una tabla sencilla sin características addcionales (`como indexes, triggers, tabla(s) de respaldo, etc`).
- Compilar el (SP) con la siguiente excepción intencional - para probar que sí está compilando:

  ```
   -- Generate intentional DivisionByZero unhandled exception: 
   /*SELECT 1/0 
   INTO V_SAMPLE 
   FROM DUAL;*/
  ```

En el punto anterior, se genera la excepción `ORA-01476` y, en mi opinión, el SP está tomando los cambios, pero, después de todos estos cambios, no puedo explicar por qué el string eliminado anterior se sigue mostrando en los resultados (*incluso cambiando el contenido del SP*).

- El 30/10/2020 añadí este string de ejemplo: `'SAMPLE - ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE)`, lo removí del SP, compilé el SP - sin este string de prueba - y sigo obteniendo este string de prueba con fecha del 30/10/2020 - fecha cuando añadí este ejemplo - a pesar de que ejecuté este SP el 05/11/2020.

¿Hay alguna manera de "refrescar" el procedimiento almacenado o qué otras pruebas puedo hacer para *refrescar* este SP?

---

Yo no soy el administrador de esta base de datos, pero, yo podría obtener mas información para compartir con el DBA - Ya le he explicado mi problema a otras personas con más experiencia, pero, no he recibido más ayuda.

Comment: ¿Es en PL/SQL de Oracle? que recuerde no existe en PL/SQL la construccion "<my_table>" ni la construccion "<ID = 1>".
Al compilar en Oracle 11g se presenta el error "PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name"

Comment: @alvalongo si, es un PLSQL de Oracle - `<my_table>` y `<ID = 1>` es un ejemplo. Edito la pregunta para dejarlo sin estos caracteres.

Comment: ¿De manera macro que es lo que se espera que suceda cuando se ejecuta el procedimiento MY_STORED_PROC? lo pregunto porque no encuentro sentido a consultar BH_APPLICATION_PARAM y que no se usen los parámetros para algo

Comment: @alvalongo lo que espero que pase cuando se ejecute `MY_STORED_PROC` es que guarde en `T_DEBUG` el stirng que se coloque allí (*sea cual sea*) y no que siga tomando un string que ya no existe en el SP - la tabla `BH_APPLICATION_PARAM` no es el problema con este SP - este SP es una versión muy reducida del SP original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente pude resolver el problema.

El error era de datos; ya que la base de datos es bastante compleja, tuve que generar una prueba completa con cambios en el texto del procedimiento almacenado `MY_STORED_PROC` - es decir, cambiar el mensaje de prueba a:

```
'Pruebas en ambiente LBASPOC - FECHA: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mi:ss')
```

Lo anterior me arrojó el siguiente resultado:

```
Pruebas en ambiente LBASPOC - FECHA: 09/11/2020 10:11:30
```

Cuando generé más pruebas, se insertaban registros con la fecha actualizada - es decir, la fecha cambiaba.

Ejemplo:

```
Pruebas en ambiente LBASPOC - FECHA: 09/11/2020 10:12:29
Pruebas en ambiente LBASPOC - FECHA: 09/11/2020 10:21:55
Pruebas en ambiente LBASPOC - FECHA: 09/11/2020 10:37:41
```

Luego descubrí que - en otras partes del programa - se realiza inserción de otros registros (en la tabla "`T_OBSERV`") basados en los datos de la tabla "`T_DEGUB`".

La solución fue modificar el SP "`MY_STORED_PROC`" para que "antes de ejecutar cualquier acción" - elimine los registros duplicados en la otra tabla "`T_OBSERV`".

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de Oracle usa?

Comment: @alvalongo Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.3.20

Comment: Esa es la versión de la herramienta SQL Developer, lo que le pregunto es la versión de la base de datos, consultar la vista  v$version.

Comment: @alvalongo gracias por el dato de `v$version`. El primer resultado es: - `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`.

Answer (score 1):

No uso SQL Developer así que no comprendo la afirmación "almacenado en SQL Developer".

En los IDE que he usado, NO "almacenan" nada, tal vez gestionan o administran archivos o proyectos.

Pero a la final es la base de datos Oracle la que almacena tablas y compila los objetos PL/SQL.

Se hizo la siguiente prueba en Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production:

```
drop table T_DEBUG;

drop table BH_APPLICATION_PARAM;

drop table BH_VAL_MESSAGES;



create table T_DEBUG
(ERR_LINE  number,
MESSAGE_INFO  varchar2(2000)
);


create table BH_APPLICATION_PARAM
(APA_NCODE   number,
 APA_CNAME   varchar2(2000)
);

insert into BH_APPLICATION_PARAM values (84,'Ventas enero');

insert into BH_APPLICATION_PARAM values (90,'Ventas Febrero');

insert into BH_APPLICATION_PARAM values (96,'Ventas Marzo');



create table BH_VAL_MESSAGES
(id   number,
 mensaje  varchar2(2000)
);

insert into BH_VAL_MESSAGES values (10,'abeja');

insert into BH_VAL_MESSAGES values(20,'burro');

insert into BH_VAL_MESSAGES values  (30,'caballo');

commit;



create or replace PROCEDURE MY_STORED_PROC(V_USER         IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                           V_NUMBER_PARAM IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                           V_ORIGIN       IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0
                                          )
AS
    CV_1                    SYS_REFCURSOR; 
    V_SAMPLE                NUMBER;
    V_USER_DB               BH_APPLICATION_PARAM.APA_CNAME%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT  BAP.APA_CNAME
    INTO    V_USER_DB
    FROM    BH_APPLICATION_PARAM BAP
    WHERE   BAP.APA_NCODE = 84;
    --
    INSERT INTO T_DEBUG (ERR_LINE, MESSAGE_INFO)
    SELECT ID, 'EXAMPLE_MESSAGE'
    FROM BH_VAL_MESSAGES; 
    --
END MY_STORED_PROC;
/

Create procedure, executed in 13 ms
Total execution time 26 ms


select *
from T_DEBUG;


Begin 
 MY_STORED_PROC('juan',
                2,
                1
               );
End;
/


select *
from T_DEBUG;

ERR_LINE MESSAGE_INFO   
      10 EXAMPLE_MESSAGE
      20 EXAMPLE_MESSAGE
      30 EXAMPLE_MESSAGE



commit;


DELETE FROM T_DEBUG;
Text
Delete - 3 row(s), executed in 2 ms
Total execution time 23 ms


commit;


Commit, executed in 1 ms
Total execution time 28 ms


select *
from T_DEBUG;


create or replace PROCEDURE MY_STORED_PROC(V_USER         IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                           V_NUMBER_PARAM IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
                                           V_ORIGIN       IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0
                                          )
AS
    CV_1                    SYS_REFCURSOR; 
    V_SAMPLE                NUMBER;
    V_USER_DB               BH_APPLICATION_PARAM.APA_CNAME%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT  BAP.APA_CNAME
    INTO    V_USER_DB
    FROM    BH_APPLICATION_PARAM BAP
    WHERE   BAP.APA_NCODE = 84;
    --
    INSERT INTO T_DEBUG (ERR_LINE, MESSAGE_INFO)
    SELECT ID, 'MENSAJE 2'
    FROM BH_VAL_MESSAGES; 
    --
END MY_STORED_PROC;
/

Create procedure, executed in 13 ms
Total execution time 26 ms



Begin 
 MY_STORED_PROC('juan',
                2,
                1
               );
End;
/

Text
PL/SQL block, executed in 4 ms
Total execution time 23 ms



select *
from T_DEBUG;

ERR_LINE MESSAGE_INFO
      10 MENSAJE 2   
      20 MENSAJE 2   
      30 MENSAJE 2   


commit;

Text                      
Commit, executed in 0 ms  
Total execution time 10 ms
```

Lo que se observa es que una vez se borran los datos de la tabla T_DEBUG, y se compila una versión nueva del procedimiento MY_STORED_PROC, y luego se ejecuta se obtienen los registros con el mensaje de la segunda versión.

El DROP de la tabla, o el DROP del procedimiento son acciones innecesarias, además que no se recomiendan pues invalidaría todos los objetos dependientes.

El TRUNCATE TABLE produce el mismo resultado que el DELETE FROM, la diferencia radica en que el TRUNCATE TABLE no queda registrado en el LOG de Oracle.

Algunas opciones a revisar:

1-Que existe el mismo nombre de procedimiento en otro esquema, que puede verificar con

```
select a.*
from dba_objects a
where a.object_name='MY_STORED_PROC'
order by owner;
```

2-Que hay un trigger en alguna tabla de algún esquema que inserta información en T_DEBUG

```
  select a.*
  from dba_triggers a
  where upper(trigger_body) like upper('%T_DEBUG%')
```

3-Que existe un proceso remoto en otra base de datos que inserte en esa tabla T_DEBUG

4-Que exista otro procedimiento, función o package que insert en la tabla T_DEBUG

```
  select a.*
  from dba_source a
  where upper(a.text) like upper('%T_DEBUG%')
  order by owner,
           type,
           name,
           line;
```

Comment: Gracias, alvalongo; he revisado como indica, pero sigo obteniendo los mismos resultados. Solo existe 1 SP válido en (1) esquema (*que es el esquema sobre el que estoy trabajando*). No existen otros SP's que hagan inserción sobre T_DEBUG y esta tabla no tiene triggers. ¿Cómo puedo revisar si existen procesos remotos?. Me comentaron que también puede ser del "application pool" - ¿Oracle tiene tal cosa? - ¿hay alguna manera de revisar o actualizar "la caché" de la base de datos?